# Extend java.util.Random to control generation of numbers

Tags: java, random

Hello I have the following tasks:

First, I am given this code that uses a method to generate random numbers 100 times:

```
public class Q3 {
    public static void printDiceRolls(Random randGenerator) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(randGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random man = new Random();
        printDiceRolls(man);
    }
}
```

Second, I am asked to make a class `LoadedDice` that extends the `Random` class:

```
public class LoadedDice extends Random {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    public int nextInt(int num) {
        // code right here
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Then I am asked to override the `public int nextInt ( int num )` and do the following

> Override the public int nextInt(int num) method such that with a 50%
>   chance, the new method always returns the largest number possible
>   (i.e., num-1), and with a 50% chance, it returns what the Random's
>   nextInt method would return

I do not quite understand what my overridden method should do in this case.

Suggestions?

Comment: First, see Random class source in http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html

Comment: *"i don't quite understand what my overridden method should do in this case."*  That seems like a matter best taken up with whoever specified the task.

Answer (score 1):

Use another Random instance to give you a 50% chance (e.g. nextInt(100) >= 50) then based on that return a constant or a real random.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one way to do this is to use (another?) random number generator with a uniform distribution and set it to return 0 or 1.  The 0/1 would be the 50% for you to make your decision upon.... either returning super.nextInt or the max number.

Comment: 'public int nextInt ( int num ) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int result = random.nextInt(2)+1;
        int finalResult = 0;
        if ( result == 1) {
        
        finalResult = num;
        }
        else if ( result == 2 ){
        
        finalResult = random.nextInt(num) ;
        }
        return finalResult;
    }'

this did not give a 50% chance. i checked using a count integer in my for loop and i should get 50 times the number 6 and 50 times others numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the `nextInt(int)` function comes up with a number between 1 and the input. In the root `Random` class, this function finds a random number within that range. What they want you to do is change that so that half the time it will return a random number in the range, but the other half the time it will give the maximum number.

In the example they gave, you're rolling a dice, so the range is 1-6. Normally, `nextInt` will find a random number between 1 and 6. But your new function will only do that half the time. The other half the time, it will return 6.

I have an idea on how you can implement that, but it seems like it would be cheating to go that far. ^^;

Comment: thanks anyway i am still trying to find that out. i made a random generator inside my method that output 1 or two. and used an if statement to check if the random generator give 1 then return the highest which is 6 and if the random generator give 2 then return super.nextInt(); but this did not give a 50/50 chance

Comment: Keep in mind that a "50%" chance on independent events (ie, flipping a coin) does NOT mean that you're guaranteed to have each option 50% of the time. I could flip a coin 50 times and have it come up heads each time. So, just because you're not getting "50 times the number 6 and 50 times others numbers" out of 100 tries does not mean it doesn't have a 50/50 chance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(super.nextBoolean())
    return num-1;
return super.nextInt(num);
```

if `num<Integer.MAX/2`, we can

```
int x = super.nextInt(num*2);
return Math.min(x, num-1);
```